# Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, ojdbc

When I'm using `ojdbc6.jar` for my application. I'm getting some weird error. Could anyone help me to solve this error ?

Here is complete stack trace of exception raised during my application execution

```
Sep 20, 2013 4:05:36 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver registerMBeans
SEVERE: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character '\n' in value part of property
    at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:618)
    at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(ObjectName.java:1382)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:303)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:213)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:209)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at conf.dbcon.dbstate(dbcon.java:42)
    at system.ObjectInfo.getObjectType(ObjectInfo.java:100)
    at system.readFile.readContents(readFile.java:36)
    at system.upload.doPost(upload.java:54)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I redownloaded pathed drivers `ojdbc6.jar` from OTN.

To check, whether you have pathed driver or not, follow these steps

```
> java -jar ojdbc6.jar
```

The unpatched jar prints

```
Oracle 11.1.0.6.0-Production JDBC 4.0 complied with JDK6
```

and the patched jar prints

```
Oracle 11.1.0.6.0-Production+ JDBC 4.0 complied with JDK6
```

If you use ojdbc5 it will say 3.0 and 1.5.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, you can download the driver from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-111060-084321.html and you can install them like this: `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.1.0.6.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgeneratePom=true`

Answer (score -1):

redownload the jar or change version of your maven/gradle artifact. I had same problem with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

change to `<version>11.2.0.4.0</version>` fixed the problem